# Do I have to provide better support when hanging a range hood from soffit framing?

Tags: kitchens, hood

I recently purchased a house and am currently renovating my kitchen. I have gutted the kitchen and changed the wall between the kitchen and living room to a half wall. The design I have now is setup to put the stove/oven against the half wall.

On the inside of this kitchen wall I have an 8' ceiling but there is a soffit with my heating duct work running through it which brings it down to 7' above where the stove top will be. The stove top comes up 36" so that leaves me 48" to work with for the range hood. I don't think I will be able to get a vented out range hood due to the pre-existing duct work so I will have to get a ductless/recirculating hood.

Is it possible for me to hang a hood down from the soffit frame? Would I have to add support to the frame to make it stronger? The frame now looks pretty weak, so I'm guessing I would.

Comment: Do you have an Ikea near where you live?

Comment: I've refocused the question, since shopping questions are not on topic here.

Comment: Yeah Edwin I have an Ikea somewhat close by.

Answer (score -1):

Every big box has said hood you need.  Do they have one that is fancy or that you will like in the depth.  Who knows?

As you can hang your "vent" from anywhere that is secure.  Note that whether you have to vent out is up to local code.  Most don't require it, meaning if they don't you want to think about not having anything - what you are getting is less effective than a ceiling.  You might also want to think about just installing a ceiling vent/fan (bathroom vent variety).